# Get Current Page Name in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

In a WordPress header.php file, is there a way to reduce this :

```
<?php if (is_page('about')): ?>
<script type="text/javascript">var page = "about";</script>
<?php endif ?>

<?php if (is_page('contact')): ?>
<script type="text/javascript">var page = "contact";</script>
<?php endif ?>

<?php if (is_page('gallery')): ?>
<script type="text/javascript">var page = "gallery";</script>
<?php endif ?>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var page = "<?php echo get_current_page() ?>";
</script>
```

Comment: @n00b32: Can you explain that statement? I don't see any reason why he cannot, or shouldn't, do this.

Comment: @n00b32: I am sure you could at least try and summarise your stance. Just saying "you shouldnt do that" means nothing. Especially on a forum like SO, and even more so from a user with as limited a reputation as yourself. If needed, post an Answer detailing the arguments against and a suggested alternate solution.

Comment: you dont have much reputation either, well i dont spend a lot of time here tho i try to help when i drop by to ask something. why not do this ? first of i see a possible xss (well not sure but still), i dont like the idea of `<php if ?><script> var x='';</script><?php endif; ?>`, and generaly you should handle that IN js not give js a variable... thats a short summary why i think its bad

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, the slight rub here is that the `is_page()` function will return TRUE if the contained string is the Post Title OR the Post Slug ([WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page)). So I will offer both solutions and you can pick which one works best for you.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php $pageDetails = get_page(); ?>
var page_title = "<?php echo str_replace( '"' , '\"' , $pageDetails->post_title ); ?>";
var page_slug  = "<?php echo str_replace( '"' , '\"' , $pageDetails->post_name  ); ?>";
</script>
```

I included the `str_replace()` bit to ensure that any page names which include quotation marks will not break your Javascript.

And, adjusted as per comments by David M, using JSON to make things a little safer...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php $pageDetails = get_page(); ?>
var page_title = <?php echo json_encode( $pageDetails->post_title ); ?>;
var page_slug  = <?php echo json_encode( $pageDetails->post_name  ); ?>;
</script>
```

Comment: Ah...Thanks. So is_page() does a search.

Comment: @n00b32: Is that the case here? As the values are being generated from within Wordpress (as opposed to just from GET variables), I would suspect that this kind of XSS issue would be far less likely to affect this specific instance.

Comment: it would be less likely but still there is a possibility ... lets leave it at that :) EOT on my end

Comment: A safe and easy way to achieve Lucanos' goal is to use `json_encode`.

Answer (score 0):

'get_page' was deprecated, updated to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php $pageDetails = get_post(); ?>
var page_title = <?php echo json_encode( $pageDetails->post_title ); ?>;
var page_slug  = <?php echo json_encode( $pageDetails->post_name  ); ?>;
var page_id  = <?php echo json_encode( $pageDetails->ID  ); ?>;
</script>
```